# .bat file random open file for 1-5 file in folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, adobe-photoshop

I need a script to run in a window to monitor my folder. When I put a jpg file in this folder, then the script running in the window should

- open that jpg file with photoshop droplet (.exe),
- wait for a while and
- run to check .jpg files again.

The script I have now works, but I need to modify it.

I want the window to open jpg file with a *random droplet* that I created: it may be 5 droplets let's say I have 5 droplets that is 1.exe, 2.exe, 3.exe, 4.exe, 5.exe instead of just 123.exe droplet (this script). How do I do this?

```
@echo off
:loop
if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.jpg" (
for %%a in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.jpg") do (
start "" /w "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\123.exe" "%%a"
ping -n 20 localhost >nul
del "%%a"
)
)
ping -n 60 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```

*Edited on 27 May 2015*
After Changing script I try move your script before "for loop" it's work but It's keep the same value in output, not random to every loop, please see my script

```
@echo off

:loop
set /a n=%random% %%5+1  (  <-- I move your line to this)
if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.jpg" (
for %%b in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.jpg") do (
start "" /w "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\%n%.exe" "%%b"
ping -n 20 localhost >nul
del "%%b"
)
)
ping -n 60 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use %random% to perform this.
`set /a n=%random%%6+1` will generate a random number between 1 and 5.

%random% % 6 generates a number between 0 and 5 so %random% % 6 + 1 generates a number between 1 and 6.

Doc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script

**EDIT** : I can't comment yet so here is how to implement this:

```
@echo off
:loop
if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.jpg" (
for %%a in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.jpg") do (
set /a n=%random%%6+1
start "" /w "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\%n%.exe" "%%a"
ping -n 20 localhost >nul
del "%%a"
)
)
ping -n 60 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```

In fact, `set /a n=...` define a new variable "n". You can use it by typing %n%.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, seem like no value in the command, window keep alert me 

"Windows cannot find 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\.exe'. Make Sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

Comment: What if you echo the value just before the start command? Like this : echo %n%

Comment: noting happen after echo  ? why ,anything wrong with my computer?

Comment: My bad. You have to write 2 percent signs: set /a n=%random% %% 6 + 1

Comment: @Dano: Correct your batch file too and double the % sign.

Comment: Thanks for helping me along, I try many way but can't solve this problem , I can't send a number to intergor, let's say I just write "set /a n=1" then echo n but nothing happen with value of n

Comment: I try to put the code in comment but it's dont seem well, so I edited my post above please see it

Comment: success! please see comment below

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks dano to let me think how to do this
after I done searching about how to use it in for loop, I finally got the answer that I have to use ! instead of % and use "SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" too

Many Thanks

```
@echo off

:loop
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.jpg" (
for %%b in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\converted\*.jpg") do (
set /a n=!random! %%5+1 
start "" /w "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\!n!.exe" "%%b"
ping -n 20 localhost >nul
del "%%b"
)
)
ping -n 60 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```